# How can I access Spring beans in no-arg constructor?

Tags: spring

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        SomeInterface something;

        // Spring magic that i don't know

        something.toString();
    }
}
```

What Spring magic do I need to use to inject a bean into "something"?

I also wouldn't mind if it was a field. It just has to be usable from within the constructor!

Answer (score 1):

The basic rules also apply to Spring:

- to construct an object, Spring needs to invoke the constructor
- Spring can't call a method of an object or set one of its fields if it isn't constructed yet
- so if you want to access a field set by Spring , you can't do that from the constructor, unless the value is passed as argument to the constructor.

This thus leaves two choices:

1. constructor injection:

   ```
   @Autowired
   public MyClass(SomeInterface something) {
       // use something
   }
   ```
2. post-construct method, called after all the injections have been done, whatever the way:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private SomeInterface something;

   @PostConstruct
   private void initialize() {
       // use something
   }
   ```

Comment: Isn't it possible to access the Spring context in a static way and getting the bean programmatically ?

Comment: You would need to have access to the application context. And that would be exactly what dependency injection tries to avoid.

Comment: Please add that as the 3rd option to your answer so i can mark it as accepted. Thanks. I know i should avoid it but didn't find any other way and i absolutely have to access the bean in constructor because of legacy code i can't change.